# 301 redirect .ebextension example - AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-301, ebextensions

Can anyone help me with a sample .ebextension file which adds a 301 redirect to IIS on a load balanced environment via Elastic Beanstalk?

I want to redirect a simple URL such as:

example.com/solutions/

to:

example.com/what-we-do/

We have an ebextension which tells IIS to serve over https, but nowhere can I find an example of someone trying to add a simple 301 redirect for one page to another page to IIS via Elastic Beanstalk.

(https redirect from AWS: https://github.com/awslabs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/dotnet/https-redirect-load-balanced-dotnet.config for info)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where do you want to redirect?

Comment: I've updated the question.